# FreeMarker how to pass variable into another variable?

Tags: java, freemarker

I use [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) as a template system and it works fine but I struggle how to define variable inside of another variable.

Here is an example of my template

```
<body>
Hello my ${friend}
</body>
```

where my friend variable should consist of another variable, for example like this:

```
data.put("id", "001");
data.put("friend", "FRIENDNAME ${id}");

Writer out = new StringWriter();
template.process(data, out);
String html = out.toString();
```

right now my output (as expected) includes variable

```
<body>
Hello my FRIENDNAME ${id}
</body>
```

How I can solve this so my result would be

```
<body>
Hello my FRIENDNAME 001
</body>
```

I tried to process result two times but that did not work and I think there must be more nice approach to solve it. Also could not find such information in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the value that you put into the data-model is itself a template. But FreeMarker will never automatically interpret what you put into a `String`. That would be quite dangerous (code injection). So you have to ask for it explicitly in the template:

```
Hello my <@friend?interpret/>!
```

But consider who can set the value of `friend`. FreeMarker templates can call the public methods of exposed Java objects, can run long loops, etc. So if a malicious user can specify the value of `friend`, they can use it for attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [interpret](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_interpret) that tells FM engine to do extra evaluation of given string (the value of "id" property)

So instead of

```
data.put("friend", "FRIENDNAME ${id}");
```

you should use

```
data.put("friend", "FRIENDNAME <@id?interpret/>");
```

Comment: tried, but that did not work, I will check a bit more about interpret though.

Comment: The two examples with the `put` call have exactly the same problem: The string value won't be interpreted as template, no mater what tricky value you put into it. It would be a vulnerability if they were interpreted.